# Update Javascript Object Value by Key/Value Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript object that looks like below:

```
selectedUsers.push({
   qid   : qid,
   first : $(this).data('emp_first'),
   last  : $(this).data('emp_last'),
   department : $(this).data('emp_dept'),
   ntid : $(this).data('emp_ntid'),
   supFirst : $(this).data('emp_sup_first'),
   supLast : $(this).data('emp_sup_last'),
   supNTID : $(this).data('emp_sup_ntid'),
   title : ($(this).data('emp_title') ? $(this).data('emp_title') : 'N/A'),
   location: ($(this).data('emp_location') ? $(this).data('emp_location') : 'N/A'),
   skillset : ($(this).data('emp_skillset') ? $(this).data('emp_skillset') : 'N/A'),
   departmentID : $(this).data('emp_dept_id'),
   titleID : $(this).data('emp_title_id'),
   regionID : $(this).data('emp_region_id'),
   instances : ($(this).data('emp_instances') != '' ? $(this).data('emp_instances').split(',') : '')
});
```

When an action is taken on my page, I need to update the value of `departmentID` in this object.

However, I need to do this for a specific result in the object.

So first I need to find the result where `selectedUsers.qid = 'bob123'` and then set the value for his `departmentID` manually.

What would be the best way to search for this result in order to edit the value for the specific key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible to save objects in your "selectedUsers" so that "qid" is their key? I am **assuming** that qid are unique values.

```
selectedUsers = {};
selectedUsers[qid] = {
   first : $(this).data('emp_first'),
   last  : $(this).data('emp_last'),
   department : $(this).data('emp_dept'),
   ntid : $(this).data('emp_ntid'),
   supFirst : $(this).data('emp_sup_first'),
   supLast : $(this).data('emp_sup_last'),
   supNTID : $(this).data('emp_sup_ntid'),
   title : ($(this).data('emp_title') ? $(this).data('emp_title') : 'N/A'),
   location: ($(this).data('emp_location') ? $(this).data('emp_location') : 'N/A'),
   skillset : ($(this).data('emp_skillset') ? $(this).data('emp_skillset') : 'N/A'),
   departmentID : $(this).data('emp_dept_id'),
   titleID : $(this).data('emp_title_id'),
   regionID : $(this).data('emp_region_id'),
   instances : ($(this).data('emp_instances') != '' ? $(this).data('emp_instances').split(',') : '')
}
```

Then all you would have to do is

```
selectedUsers['bob123'].departmentID = yourNewValue;
```

**IF NOT...**

Then you will just have to loop the entire array (selectedUsers) until you find the one where qid matches your search.

```
for (var index=0, limit=selectedUsers.length; index < limit; ++index) {
    if(selectedUsers[index].qid == "bob123"){
      selectedUsers[index].deparmentID = "yourvalue";  
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is all happening on the client and not in some datastore. In that case I would look into the [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/docs#find) library- specifically the `find` method:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// → 

object for 'barney'
```

so in your case you would have something like

```
var user = _.find(selectedUsers, function (user) {user.qid === searchId; });
user.departmentID = someOtherId;
// whatever else you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

User underscore.js [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) Function

example:
    `var user = _.find(selectedUsers, function (item) { return item.departmentID === deartmentID});`
    `user.departmentID = yourNewValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `selectedUsers` is  an array, you could do something like this:

```
function setSelectedUsersDepartment(qid, departmentID) {
    for (var i in selectedUsers) {
        var user = selectedUsers[i];
        if (user.qid === qid) {
            user.departmentID = departmentID;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you can use the ES6 [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function (no IE support):

```
function setSelectedUsersDepartment (qid, newDepartmentID) {
    var user = selectedUsers.find(user => user.qid === qid);
    if (user !== undefined) {
        user.departmentID = newDepartmentID;
    }
}
```

if you want to set the departmentID for bob, you call the function like this

```
setSelectedUsersDepartment('bob123', 'new_departmentID');
```